# Ace snippet codecomplation use square bracket

Tags: javascript, php, code-snippets, ace-editor

My question is: is anyone know how to add ACE snippet file row which contain square brackets? 
I add it as a normal syntax but unfortunately the code completation can not find that row(s) which contain square brackets.

Example:

```
VARIABLE['KEY_ONE']['KEY_TWO']
```

If user start to wirte in snipet editor on webpage and write: VAR... I would like offer some selectable values like the example above.

Can anybody help to solve this problem?
I already tried to protect square brackets:

```
VARIABLE\['KEY_ONE'\]\['KEY_TQO'\]
```

...or duplicate brackets:

```
VARIABLE[['KEY_ONE']][['KEY_TQO']]
```

...but both of that do not work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ace uses textmate snippet format, so `[` doesn't have any special meaning.
if you add:

```
snippet VAR
    VARIABLE['KEY_ONE']['KEY_TWO']
```

that is `snippet VAR\n\tVARIABLE['KEY_ONE']['KEY_TWO']` it should work.

Comment: Thank you! It works fine! it looks like problem was that I used a too short variable name...it was only one character. Now I am using longer one and it works fine! Please let me one more question: do you have any experience or knowledge about...so if user type a square brakets the possible codecomplation list lost. Is any solution for codecomplation 'popup' do not disappear if user type a square brakets? Thanks!

Comment: what are you trying to do?